# how to have a wildcard in mysql statement with '=' sign

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have pre parameters determining what is passed into my query.  In one case I want to search for ALL UUIDs, and in another case I want to search for specific UUID numbers.  I would like to do this in one query statement instead of breaking it into two seperate calls (like below)

example 1:

```
$uuidtosearchfor = "1234";
$query = "SELECT ID,name,UUID FROM table where active =  1 AND UUID ='$uuidtosearchfor'";
```

exmaple 2:

```
$query = "SELECT ID,name,UUID FROM table where active =  1";
```

so instead I want this:

```
if(rule1)
       $uuidtosearchfor = "*"; // return everything
else
 $uuidtosearchfor = "2134"; // return everything
        $query = "SELECT ID,name,UUID FROM table where active =  1 AND UUID = '$uuidtosearchfor' ";
```

Comment: In SQL, you can't have a "wildcard" with an `=` operator, only with a `LIKE` or `REGEXP` operator.... although you can (if you really have to) use LIKE instead of `=` without a wildcard

Comment: If you have a wildcard, remove the ` AND UUID = '$uuidtosearchfor' "` from your where clause...

Answer (score 2):

If you use `LIKE` instead of `=`, you can use `%` as wildcard. But `LIKE` isn't exactly the same as `=`.

With `=` you could construct the query as `UUID=UUID`. The downside is, you cannot use prepared statements and have to take care about escaping the parameter yourself.

Actually, I don't see how any of these makes your life easier. I'd rather construct the query such that the condition is not added if you want to match all uuids.